# fvwm MinOverlapPlacement: automatically arrange windows from left to right instead of top to bottom?

Tags: x11, window-manager, window-management, fvwm

Is there some way to tell fvwm3 to arrange windows from left to right instead of top to bottom?

Currently I am using

```
#
# Placement
#
Style   *   !UsePPosition
Style   *   UseTransientPPosition
Style   *   MinOverlapPlacement
Style   *   MinOverlapPlacementPenalties 1 5 1 1 0 50
```

I found FvwmRearrange(1), but I don't want to rearrange existing windows. They should be placed immediately on the left side of the screen as far as possible. Looking for "arrange" or "placement" did not reveal an option to modify fvwm3's current behavior, but hopefully I am not too blind to see?